# images not showing in pdf preview?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, pdf

Strange feeling that if i want to preview a pdf on a controller alongside an image the  only way i can get it to work is to use a defined segue from the previous view controller, maybe i'm not clear. How to i get an image to show up on a preview of a QuickLook action without having to segue in and not just modal into the view ? Is this logical ?

I dev an app which generates PDF's, and i'm giving the user the possibility to preview them....but when these have an image....boom the image disappears from the preview...unless i use a segue then no problem, seems weird though. Any suggestions ?....thanks in advance...

Comment: Show some code/screenshots as to what you have tried so far and whats not working for you.

Comment: thanks for coming back to me. I admit that i have just left the use of identified segues as is as it is working but i just thought it strange. here is an example of the quickly action preview that  i am using :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (CFRange)renderPage:(NSInteger)pageNum withTextRange:(CFRange)currentRange
   andFramesetter:(CTFramesetterRef)framesetter
{

CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Put the text matrix into a known state. This ensures
// that no old scaling factors are left in place.
CGContextSetTextMatrix(currentContext, CGAffineTransformIdentity);

// Create a path object to enclose the text. Use 72 point
// margins all around the text.

#pragma-----------here to disclose the height of text on pdf preview

CGRect    frameRect = CGRectMake(40, 72, 468,  350);
CGMutablePathRef framePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddRect(framePath, NULL, frameRect);

[_imageView1 setImage:theImage1];

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(40, 50, 130, 130);
[ProgramPDFViewController drawImage:theImage1 inRect:frame];

CGSize size = theImage1.size;
CGFloat ratio = 0;
if (size.width > size.height) {
    ratio = 44.0 / size.width;
} else {
    ratio = 44.0 / size.height;
}
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, ratio * size.width, ratio * size.height);


UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
[theImage1 drawInRect:rect];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
CTFrameRef frameRef = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, currentRange, framePath, NULL);
CGPathRelease(framePath);
CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, kDefaultPageHeight);
CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);
 CTFrameDraw(frameRef, currentContext);
currentRange = CTFrameGetVisibleStringRange(frameRef);
currentRange.location += currentRange.length;
currentRange.length = 0;
CFRelease(frameRef);

return currentRange;
}
```